# asp.net core docker linux assembly not found

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

when deploying the asp.net core 2.2 app to docker on linux, when running dotnet someprogram.dll, it complains about the dependency dll not found. but obviously the dll is at the same folder as someprogram.dll, the message specifically complains about the assembly at 'lib/dotnetstandard2.0/someassembly.dll' is missing. why is that? where should the dll be?

here's the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build 
WORKDIR /app 
COPY . . 
WORKDIR /app/WebService 
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app/out 

FROM build AS publish 
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/out 

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime 
WORKDIR /app 
COPY --from=build /app/out . ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebService.dll"]
```

Comment: What is your `WORKDIR` folder and your `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` command?

Comment: can you post your Dockerfile and the docker command you run?

Comment: here's the dockerfile:

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /app


COPY . .


WORKDIR /app/WebService

RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app/out


FROM build AS publish

RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/out


FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/out .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebService.dll"]

Answer (score 0):

turns out that this line is causing the trouble.

```
FROM build AS publish
```

after commenting it out, the app starts working.

Here's the `Dockerfile`

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build 
WORKDIR /app 

COPY . . 

WORKDIR /app/WebService 
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/out 

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime 
WORKDIR /app 
COPY --from=build /app/out . 

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebService.dll"]
```